# How to keep duplicate data count in elastic Search using ReST API?

Tags: elasticsearch

## ***How to keep duplicate data count in elastic Search using ReST API?***

Is it possible to keep same data with same index in elastic Search, but we should be able to see various versions of it ?
and in Overview area it should show
docs 5(6).

Answer (score 1):

You can store as many versions of a document you want as long as you use different IDs. (Note that there is a `_version` property that ES manages for you, but it's only for resolving conflicts. ES doesn't give you access to old versions of docs.)

```
   % curl -s -XPUT localhost:9200/test/foo/1 -d '{"yo":"brah","version":1}' | j
   {
       "_id": "1", 
       "_index": "test", 
       "_type": "foo", 
       "_version": 1, 
       "ok": true
   }
   % curl -s -XPUT localhost:9200/test/foo/2 -d '{"yo":"brah","version":2}' | j
   {
       "_id": "2", 
       "_index": "test", 
       "_type": "foo", 
       "_version": 1, 
       "ok": true
   }
   % curl -s localhost:9200/test/_search | j
   {
       "_shards": {
           "failed": 0, 
           "successful": 5, 
           "total": 5
       }, 
       "hits": {
           "hits": [
               {
                   "_id": "1", 
                   "_index": "test", 
                   "_score": 1.0, 
                   "_source": {
                       "version": 1, 
                       "yo": "brah"
                   }, 
                   "_type": "foo"
               }, 
               {
                   "_id": "2", 
                   "_index": "test", 
                   "_score": 1.0, 
                   "_source": {
                       "version": 2, 
                       "yo": "brah"
                   }, 
                   "_type": "foo"
               }
           ], 
           "max_score": 1.0, 
           "total": 2
       }, 
       "timed_out": false, 
       "took": 12
   }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question.                           Suppose if I do not provide id specifically and keep system generated id. In that case same data will be stored with different id but version will be 1 and API's (for eg. ReST API, Java API) used for the purpose does not make any difference ?

Comment: Right. Using the system-generated ID would have the same effect.  I just constructed the example that way because you have to supply it for a REST PUT.